# Exception catching in C++ doesn't work anymore after linking in C library

Tags: c++, exception

I have a fairly large C++ project (a data analysis program called [QSoas](http://qsoas.org)) that links with several libraries:

- Qt (linked in dynamically
- Ruby (linked in dynamically)
- The GNU scientific library (linked in statically)

While the whole compilation process is painless in Linux (my primary development environment), it took me some time to get things built under windows (using mingw-based tools).

Now, I'm linking in a new static library, [mruby](http://mruby.org), in order to transition to mruby as an embedded interpreter rather than Ruby, and suddenly exceptions don't work anymore: instead of catching exceptions, I just get the following message on the terminal:

```
abnormal program termination
```

The same program linked under Linux runs fine.

Are there any basic caveat I may have overlooked ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the C DLL is registering a vectored exception handler that could be catching the exception and preventing the stack unwinding from occurring.

Comment: The AddVectoredExceptionHandler symbol is indeed imported in the ruby DLL. I'm now trying to remove the ruby library altogether, keeping only the mruby library (and the other ones).

Comment: Doesn't work, but it seems like it may be due to the presence of the `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` link flags that had become necessary a long time ago to build with Ruby.